# How can you delete the contents of multiple cells at the same time in Excel? I am using a PC with an Apple keyboard

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can you delete the contents of multiple cells at the same time in Excel? I am using a PC with an Apple keyboard. It doesn't work when I click "delete" or "fn+delete". I can't figure out the keyboard shortcut to do it.

Comment: "using a PC with an Apple keyboard" Why?

Comment: There are no shortcuts on the Apple keyboard to delete selected cells at once. If you only want to operate through the keyboard, you can only do it in steps, as Wasif describes it.

Answer (score 1):

The action you're looking for is `clear contents`. You can see that if you right-click on a region of multiply selected cells. Fn-Delete does it on my Macbook Pro running Excel in a Windows VM.

Answer (score 1):

First select all the cells to delete. Then keep pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>/<kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete contents of first cell and then <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd>.